# Spring URL Redirect

Tags: java, spring, url

I am new to spring. I am following heroku - spring - tomcat webapplication tutorial. The application works perfect but I want to change url path it didn't work. The application works well under example.com/people/ path because web.xml file like that

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/people/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and controller file is

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String listPeople(Map<String, Object> map) {

    map.put("person", new Person());
    map.put("peopleList", personService.listPeople());

    return "people";
}
```

I want to change url path example.com/people/ to example.com/ but when I changed web.xml like that

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

It doesn't work for me. How can I redirect all url request to my controller class without using /people/*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove asterisk in url-pattern.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: example.com/ still goes to my welcome page.
<welcome-file-list>
       <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

Comment: If you remove the welcome-file-list, it should be handled by the controller which has `@RequestMapping("/")`, in your case listPeople handler.

Comment: Also it requires to delete index.jsp